# Search using POST-data in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to add the ratebeer.com search function to Google Chrome (the one to the top right on http://www.ratebeer.com/). The problem is that it's search function uses POST instead of GET, so you can't add the %s to the url in order to get it to work.

It does work just fine in Firefox though (just right clicking on the search field and adding a keyword works). The information about which postdata field is used doesn't show up in Firefox itself, but I exported the bookmark file and all the relevant information should be that the URL is http://www.ratebeer.com/findbeer.asp, and the only postdata needed is BeerName%3D%25s (from the bookmark file: POST_DATA="BeerName%3D%25s" LAST_CHARSET="ISO-8859-1" ).

Is there a way of getting Chrome search to work with postdata? If not, perhaps there's a way to do this in javascript? e.g. a one-liner with a %s in it, that would probably work with chrome.